# Exoplayer local path with Question Mark

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am developing music application. I have been using exoplayer to play music. I have lived a problem and couldn't find any solution. My problem is that ı have downloaded song file from internet. This song name contains "?" mark. I create path for this song file and use its name. After song downloaded successfully. I play with exoplayer. I create path for this song and set to exoplayer but it couldn't be played.

Song path = /storage/emulated/0/mymusic/downloads/How am I?_009.mp3

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

```
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri, null, null);

    exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
```

I don't want replace "?" with any character.
How can I play?
Anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: use `Uri#fromFile()` or `Uri.Builder`

Comment: Thanks @pskink that solved my poblem

Comment: @paskink thank you for your answer! you might also want to use something like this if youre planning on playing both offline and online music: isOnlinePath(path) ? Uri.parse(path) : Uri.fromFile(new File(path))

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to use something like this if youre planning on playing both offline and online music:

```
 MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource
.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
.createMediaSource(
    isOnlinePath(path) ? Uri.parse(path) : Uri.fromFile(new File(path))
    , null, null);

exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

boolean isOnlinePath(String path) {
     return path != null &&
      (path.contains("http") ||
       path.contains(".m3u") ||
       path.contains(".pls"));
}
```